# Javascript Array.prototype.filter() not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this piece of code running on the client that filters a list of events:

```
if (res)
{
    eventList.filter(function(event) {

        const out = res.find(function(visibility) { return visibility.ID == event.id; }) == undefined;
        return out;
    });

    alert(eventList);
}

displayEvents(eventList);
```

The problem is that even when `out` is `false` the element is not filtered out.

Just for debug I tried to `return false` in any case and the resulting array still had all the initial elements:

```
eventList.filter(function(event) {

    return out;
});
```

What am I doing wrong here??

*EDIT:*

`res` is an array of JSON objects (containg only `ID` field) returned by the server, while `eventList` is a list of Facebook events, passed to this callback function from a Facebook API request

Comment: `.filter()` doesn't change the original array. You need to do `eventList = eventList.filter(..)`. Also, don't use `alert()` for debugging.

Comment: God, how can I be that stupid ... Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Array.prototype.filter` does not change array inplace, it returns new array made of items that satisfies the provided predicate. It should look like this

```
var result = eventList.filter(function(event) {
    return res.find(function(visibility) { return visibility.ID == event.id; }) === undefined;
});
```

You don't need to declare and assign variable and then return it from function, you can simply return expression