# Can't filter an array in reference hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I'm trying to filter out found objects in a array in a hidden object game I'm working on. When a player clicks at the right coordinate and selects the right object, that object is taken away from an array. To do that, I'm storing the array in a `ref` value as `let items = useRef([])` since I'm not actually rendering the objects.

Finding player's selection inside the array doesn't have any issue at all.

```
const item = items.current.find(item => item.name === toy)

if(!item){
  setFound('Not quite, try again!')
  return;
}
```

However filtering player's selection simply does nothing

```
item.current.filter((item)=>item.name!==toy);
```

My first option was actually to store `items` in a state but `items` never reach zero. I suspect that happens immediately since states work asynchronously, which means I can actually see the deletion one render ahead. On the other hand, a plain variable isn't recommended because I'm setting it inside `useEffect`, `items` in reality stores data from a data base.

React documentation states that [references](https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs) are mutable values but I've not been able to changing with `Array.splice()` either.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong please?

This is my code:

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import supabase from "../config/supabaseClient";
import Image from "./image"
import Timer from "./timer";

const Game = ()=>{
  let items = useRef([]);
  const [fetchError, setFetchError] = useState(null);
  const [found, setFound] = useState("");
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(()=>{

    const fetchOptions = async()=>{
      const{data,error} = await supabase
        .from('items')
        .select();

      if(error){
        setFetchError('Could not fetch items');
        items.current = [];
      }

      if(data){
        items.current = data;
        setFetchError(null);
      }
    }
    fetchOptions();
  },[])

  function handleAction(click, toy){
    
    const item = items.current.find(item => item.name === toy )

    if(!item){
      setFound(`Not quite, try again!`);
      return;
    }

    if(click.x>item.left&&click.x<item.right){
      if(click.y<item.bottom&&click.y>item.top){
        setFound(`Well done! You've found Sarah's ${toy}`);
        items.current.filter((item)=>item.name!==toy);
        console.log(items.current)
        if(items.length === 0){
          console.log('Winner');
          navigate("/leaderboard", {state:time});
        }
      }
    }else{
      setFound(`Not quite, try again!`);
      return;
    }
  }

  return(
    <>
      {fetchError&&(<p>{fetchError}</p>)}
      <Timer time={time} setTime={setTime}/>
      <Image handleAction={handleAction}/>
      <p>{found}</p>
    </>
  );

}

export default Game;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Array.prototype.filter() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619067/javascript-array-prototype-filter-not-working)

Comment: `items.current = items.current.filter((item)=>item.name!==toy);`

Comment: Read the documentation for filter. It returns a new array....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56587032/how-to-filter-array-with-hooks

Comment: Thanks @Konrad! It wasn't storing `filter` anywhere. It all makes sense

Comment: Yeah @epascarello, I read the documentation but didn't apply it well in my code. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter` method returns a new array with the elements that pass the condition, but it doesn't modify the original array in place. So you need to assign the filtered array back to the ref's current value.

```
items.current = items.current.filter(item => item.name !== toy)
```

Also, when you're checking to see if no items are left, you should access `items.current.length` instead since `items` is a ref.

```
if (items.current.length === 0) {
  console.log('Winner');
  navigate("/leaderboard", { state: time });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @HassamUdDin! I also changed the `items.current.length` line that wasn't working either.